# "Invalid or expired token" error when trying to access Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to use [Application-only authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) to access Twitter API. I can get a Bearer token correctly (at least I think so!) but when I try to use the token to make an API call I always get `Invalid or expired token` error.

```
twitter_consumer_key = b"<MY_APP_CONSUMER_KEY>"
twitter_consumer_secret = b"<MY_APP_SECRET_KEY>"
twitter_keys = base64.standard_b64encode(twitter_consumer_key + b':' + twitter_consumer_secret)

content = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
post_headers = {
    b'Authorization': b'Basic ' + twitter_keys,
    b'Content-Type': b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
}

twitter_bearer = requests.post('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', headers=post_headers, data=content).json()['access_token']
twitter_headers = {
    b'Authorization': b'Bearer ' + base64.b64encode(twitter_bearer.encode('utf-8')),
}
response = requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=itechbrij",
                                 headers=twitter_headers).text
```

`print(twitter_followers)` gives `{"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes in **BOLD**:

twitter_keys = base64.standard_b64encode((twitter_consumer_key + ':' + twitter_consumer_secret)**.encode('utf8')**)

post_headers = {
    **'User-Agent': 'YOUR USER AGENT STRING',**
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + twitter_keys**.decode('utf8')**,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
}

twitter_bearer = requests.post(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', 
    headers=post_headers, 
    **params**=content).json()['access_token']